# Can the parent of an Introduction be a class?

Tags: aop, spring-aop

In the official documentation it is claimed that the parent has to be an interface, yet in the example given it is a class (class UsageTracking). How comes?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-introductions

```
@Aspect
public class UsageTracking {

    @DeclareParents(value="com.xzy.myapp.service.*+", defaultImpl=DefaultUsageTracked.class)
    public static UsageTracked mixin;

    @Before("com.xyz.myapp.CommonPointcuts.businessService() && this(usageTracked)")
    public void recordUsage(UsageTracked usageTracked) {
        usageTracked.incrementUseCount();
    }

}
```

Comment: `UsageTracking` is the Aspect . The parent interface is `UsageTracked` and the example looks valid. I guess you are confused with the `Aspect` class name and the interface mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation example : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-introductions

- The aspect class is `UsageTracking`
- The parent interface is `UsageTracked`
- The implementation class is `DefaultUsageTracked`

The example looks valid. The confusion here appears to be about the `Aspect` class name and the interface name.